# How to run a function when notification fires and app isn't running

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

How to run or execute a method when a local notification fires and the app isn't running or it's running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications don't trigger background execution, only remote notifications do that (when setup properly).